# Split strings in a column based on text values and numerical values such as patindex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that displays stock market options data like below:

```
GME240119C00020000
QQQ240119C00305000
NFLX240119P00455000
```

I want to be able to split these up so they show up like:

```
GME|240119|C|00020000
QQQ|240119|C|00305000
NFLX|240119|P|00455000
```

I was able to split the first portion with the ticker name by using the code below, but I don't know how to split the rest of the strings.

```
case patindex('%[0-9]%', str)
    when 0 then str
    else left(str, patindex('%[0-9]%', str) -1 ) 
end
from t
```

edit:  for anyone who is wondering, I used Dale's solution below to get my desired outcome. I edited the query he provided to make the parts show up as individual columns

```
select
    substring(T.contractSymbol,1,C1.Position-1) as a 
    ,substring(T.contractSymbol,C1.Position,6) as b
    ,substring(S1.Part,1,1) as c
    ,substring(S1.Part,2,len(S1.Part)) as d
from Options_Data_All T
cross apply (
    values (patindex('%[0-9]%', T.contractSymbol))
) C1 (Position)
cross apply (
    values (substring(contractSymbol, C1.Position+6, len(T.contractSymbol)))
) S1 (Part);
```

Comment: A stock symbol (ticker) can consist of numbers - beware!

Comment: Ah...more problems! Haha, do you have any suggestions I can go about accomplishing my goal then?

Comment: @Cha2 the first step is to ensure your question covers all edge cases.

Comment: Hi Dale - I tried on my database, and it's definitely working how you described, but I think I was not explaining my problem clearly enough. My goal is to get those parts split up into individual columns and the "|" was just meant to be shown as a divider for where the string should be split for each individual column.

edit: but I just removed the + "|" portions and just added the "as column1" etc... thanks it worked! :)

Comment: I just selected your answer as the accepted answer, but it won't let me upvote it because my account is too new....Thanks again Dale

Comment: @cha2 ar, you need to be clear when you want data in separate columns - like I have done showing tabular data, just add more columns. Anyway its trivial to remove the `+ '|' +` parts and replace with `,` to give separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep doing what you started doing by using `SUBSTRING`. So as you did find the first number and actually in your case, based on the data provided, everything else is fixed length, so you don't have to search anymore, just split the string.

```
declare @Test table (Contents nvarchar(max));

insert into @Test (Contents)
values
('GME240119C00020000'),
('QQQ240119C00305000'),
('NFLX240119P00455000');

select
    substring(T.Contents,1,C1.Position-1) + '|' + substring(T.Contents,C1.Position,6) + '|' + substring(S1.Part,1,1) + '|' + substring(S1.Part,2,len(S1.Part))
from @Test T
cross apply (
    values (patindex('%[0-9]%', T.Contents))
) C1 (Position)
cross apply (
    values (substring(Contents, C1.Position+6, len(T.Contents)))
) S1 (Part);
```

Returns:

| Data |
| --- |
| GME|240119|C|00020000 |
| QQQ|240119|C|00305000 |
| NFLX|240119|P|00455000 |

If one can assume that all but the first column are fixed width then a simple `SUBSTRING` solution would suffice e.g.

```
select 
    substring(Contents,1,len(Contents)-15)
    + '|' + substring(Contents,len(Contents)-14,6)
    + '|' + substring(Contents,len(Contents)-8,1)
    + '|' + substring(Contents,len(Contents)-7,8) [Data]
from @Test;
```

Note: `CROSS APPLY` is just a fancy way to use a sub-query to avoid needing to repeat a calculation.